# How to deploy multiple Web Api containers to Azure using Docker-Compose

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose

I am pretty new to docker. I am trying to deploy a multi container web api project.
I follow the way like   https://medium.com/@kkajasu/deployment-in-azure-for-one-container-dbe4e8e031c1 .In this way how to manage multi container .please give me some ideas .thank you

Comment: What Azure service will you be using?  App Service or AKS?

Comment: App service azure service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the Web App, you need to select Docker Image, then Docker Compose, then the registry where your images are stored.  You then need to provide a YAML file where you'll define the container images and the network names and ports.  Here's an example:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  webapiconverter:
    image: myacr.azurecr.io/converter
    ports:
      - '80'
    restart: always

  webapiinventory:
    image: myacr.azurecr.io/inventory
    ports:
      - '80'
    restart: always  

  apigateway:
    image: myacr.azurecr.io/apigateway
    ports:
      - '80:80'
    restart: always
```

Note that Web App can only expose port 80 and 8080 so if you have multiple APIs in multiple containers, your point of entry will likely be an API gateway like Ocelot.  You'll need to define the routes in a JSON file.  Here's an example:

```
{
  "ReRoutes": [
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/f_to_c?f={degrees}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "converter",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/converter/{degrees}"
    },        
    {
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/inventory/{sku}",
      "DownstreamScheme": "http",
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "webapi",
          "Port": 80
        }
      ],
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/api/inventory/{sku}"
    }

  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://backend.azurewebsites.net"
  }
}
```

Here's the reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot

Comment: https://github.com/kajasumanie/demo6  . i did like this but still there are error . please help me to fix it . i gave different port number then i create a configuration file.

Comment: I deploy the project by right click the project . now i am confused how to publish it .

Comment: You need to push your containers to a container registry like Docker Hub or Azure Container Registry.  They will be pulled by App Service using the info you provide in the YAML file.